# Can Twilio send sms to google Project fi phones? Anyone has used it?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, google-project-fi

We are using Twilio API to send sms. Can we add the to phone as Project Fi phone numbers? Can Twilio send sms to Project fi phones? Has anyone has any experience in doing this?

Comment: I've had trouble sending SMS to Project Fi phone using basic Twiml Bin. I have a support ticket logged, will try to remember to come back and report the answer from twilio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to [send SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) to Projectfi users. However if you are using a short code you can do so as long as the number isn't a VOIP number. You can use the [Lookups API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups) to determine what kind of number a user has before sending to avoid sending to VOIP numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I'm both a Project Fi and Twilio user. Everything works as expected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12805002)

Comment: @Hidde How does this not provide an answer?

Comment: I have to agree I don't know what @Hiddie is talking about

Answer (score 0):

I have a Project Fi number and a Google Voice number. Twilio SMS works only to the Google Voice number for me.

I also have trouble getting many SMS from companies like banks, etc for 2-factor. I always have to direct them to the Google Voice number, or go for a voice call instead.

Think I'll call Project Fi and ask about this.